# iOS addTarget:action:forControlEvents only works for one of my button when assigned in for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, for-loop, uibutton

I have a view that contains a couple of subviews, each of these subviews have a transparent button on it. I place these views on my main UIView in a for-loop, in this loop I also assigns a target and an action for the subviews button property. My problem is that only the first view and button that gets created in the loop works (that is, it's action is getting called when I click it).

The relevant part of the loop looks like this:

```
// _categories is an array
for (int i = 0; i < _categories.count; i++) {

     [...]

    Category *category = [_categories objectAtIndex:i]; 
    CategoryView *categoryView = [[CategoryView alloc] initWithFrame:categoryRect andTitle:category.name];
    [...]

    categoryView.categoryButton.tag = [category.categoryId intValue];
    [categoryView.categoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openCategoryWithId:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:categoryView];

    [...]
}
```

The action looks like this:

```
- (void)openCategoryWithId:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Only gets called when I click on the first views button. 
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

I have tried to create a strong property for the subview, but that didn't help.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: If you modify the buttons to not be transparent, do they appear to be placed correctly? They might all be piling on top of one another because `categoryRect` isn't being set properly (We can't see where that is set in the sampled code provided.)

Comment: @Paul thanks, you were right. Their position was completely wrong in categoryView. They weren't piling up, but your assumption was right. Add it as an answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the buttons were not being positioned correctly because of `categoryRect`.